# Error on creating creating a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I got an error in creating a ListView here's the error:

```
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.databasetest/com.example.databasetest.ViewData}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.example.databasetest.ViewData.onCreate(ViewData.java:19)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-30 18:42:42.177: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  ... 11 more
```

i don't why the emulator looking for the android:R.id.list

here's my code on the Activity that will use the listView

```
package com.example.databasetest;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ViewData extends ListActivity {

    private DBHandler dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_data);

        displayListView();

    }
    private void displayListView() {

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getData();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                DBHandler.COL_NAME,
                DBHandler.COL_ADDRESS,
                DBHandler.COL_PHONE,
                DBHandler.COL_EMAIL
        };
        int[] to = new int[] { 
                R.id.name,
                R.id.address,
                R.id.phone,
                R.id.email,
        };
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.country_info, 
                cursor, 
                columns, 
                to,
                0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

and here is the two XML file that i'm gonna use for the listView
view_data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly country_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Address: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Phone: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Email: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/continent"
        android:text="Test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:text="Test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ViewData extends Activity
```

Change **listactivity** to **activity**.

Create your **class as Activity** 
because **list activity** always **uses built in list** not ur customised list.

Answer (score 2):

Put this:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

and in the XML

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: But i think it is better to you change your ListActivity for Activity
like Captain America said